# Convert JSON to table, with headers of "Key" and "Value"

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON output:

```
 [
  {
    "enabled": "true",
    "policy_profile": "custom",
    "scan_local_files": "true",
    "local_file_types": "all",
    "scan_network_files": "false",
    "limit_file_size": "false",
    "enable_archive_scanning": "false",
    "scan_boot_sectors": "true",
    "scan_only_new_changes": "true",
    "scan_for_keyloggers": "true",
    "scan_for_puas": "true",
    "deferred_scanning": "true",
    "scan_action_for_infected_files": "Move to quarantine",
    "scan_action_for_infected_files_secondary": "Move to quarantine",
    "scan_action_for_suspect_files": "Move to quarantine",
    "scan_action_for_suspect_files_secondary": "Deny Access"
  }
]
```

What I have been struggling with is trying to make the output look like an inverse table.  I can get it to look like the following:

```
deferred_scanning       enable_archive_scanning enabled limit_archive_size      limit_file_size local_file_types        max_archive_depth       policy_profile  scan_action_for_infected_files  scan_action_for_infected_files_secondary   scan_action_for_suspect_files   scan_action_for_suspect_files_secondary scan_boot_sectors       scan_for_keyloggers     scan_for_puas   scan_local_files  scan_network_files       scan_only_new_changes
-----------------       ----------------------- ------- ------------------      --------------- ----------------        -----------------       --------------  ------------------------------  ----------------------------------------   -----------------------------   --------------------------------------- -----------------       -------------------     -------------   ----------------  ------------------       ---------------------
true    true    true    5       false   all     6       custom  Move to quarantine      Move to quarantine      Move to quarantine      Deny Access     true    true    true    true    false   true
```

But it's a little messy, and I want to have something like:

```
Attribute           Value
---------           -----
enabled             true
policy_profile      custom
scan_local_files    true
...
```

Any help or pointing out an existing SE question that covers this specific issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The outer structure of your JSON document is an array. It only contains a single element, but should we assume that it _may_ contain several elements?  If so, what should the output look like when it does contain several elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for your input data

```
jq -r '.[] | to_entries[] | [.key,.value] | @tsv' file.json
```

Output (tab separated):

```
enabled true
policy_profile  custom
scan_local_files        true
local_file_types        all
scan_network_files      false
limit_file_size false
enable_archive_scanning false
scan_boot_sectors       true
scan_only_new_changes   true
scan_for_keyloggers     true
scan_for_puas   true
deferred_scanning       true
scan_action_for_infected_files  Move to quarantine
scan_action_for_infected_files_secondary        Move to quarantine
scan_action_for_suspect_files   Move to quarantine
scan_action_for_suspect_files_secondary Deny Access
```

It's then relatively straightforward to use `awk` or some other tool to format this in whatever way you want.

If you want the `Attribute` and `Value` listed as the first row, change the command like this

```
jq -r  '[ "Attribute", "Value"], ( .[] | to_entries[] | [.key,.value] ) | @tsv' file.json
```

Reference [jq: print key and value for each entry in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34227629), which has just introduced me to `to_entries`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!